# R - Irregular metadata; create df from large single column

Tags: r, transformation, ncbi

The title doesn't really do my question justice, because there are probably a few ways to skin this cat. But I picked one approach and went with it. This is what I'm working with:

I've pulled all the metadata for a particular [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosample/?term=(american%20gut%20project)%20AND%20biosample_sra[filter]%20AND%20public[filter]) in the NCBI database using the "Send to:" option on their interface and downloading a .txt file.

In total, I have ~23k samples, each with up to 609 unique questions and answers from a questionnaire totaling **8M+ obs of 1 variable** when read as a .csv. To my dismay, the metadata are irregular. Some samples have 140 associated key/value pairs. Others have 492. I've included a header of a sample below.

```
1: qiita_sid_10317:10317.BLANK1.6H.GUELPH
Identifiers: BioSample: SAMEA4790059; SRA: ERS2609990
Organism: metagenome
Attributes:
    /Alias="qiita_sid_10317:10317.BLANK1.6H.GUELPH"
    /description="American Gut control"
    /ENA checklist="ERC000011"
    /INSDC center alias="UCSDMI"
    /INSDC center name="University of California San Diego Microbiome Initiative"
    /INSDC first public="2018-07-13T17:03:10Z"
    /INSDC last update="2018-07-13T14:50:03Z"
    /INSDC status="public"
    /SRA accession="ERS2609990"
```

I've tried (including but not limited to):

- Read .txt file (adding a delimiter hasn't made a difference, am I missing something here?)
- I've tried reading the data using various delimiters
- I've even removed the header data in Sublime Text, leaving only "Attributes:" and the "/"-delimited key/value pairs in order to mess with the column that way
- I've split the column found all unique values in col1 to maybe create a df from scratch, etc etc.

**Can't seem to get past the cleaning steps:**

```
samples <- read.csv("~/biosample_result_full.txt")
samples_split <- cSplit(samples, splitCols = sample$Colname, sep = "=")
samples_split$Attributes_1 <- gsub(" ", "_", samples_split$Attributes_1)
questions <- unique(samples_split$Attributes_1)
```

**Ideally, each sample and associated metadata would be transformed into rows, with each "Attribute"/question as the column name.**

[image: This]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the website you've linked to, allows fot the option to export data to xml. I strongly suggest to do so. R can hande/parse xml-files very efficient.

When I download the first three results from that site to a file `biosample_result.xml` , it's easy to process using the `xml2`-package

```
library( xml2 )
library( magrittr )

doc <- read_xml( "./biosample_result.xml")
#gret all BioSample nodes
BioSample.Nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, "//BioSample")
#build a data.frame
data.frame( 
  sample_name = xml_find_first( BioSample.Nodes , ".//Id[@db='SRA']") %>% xml_text(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#   sample_name
# 1  ERS2609990
# 2  ERS2609989
# 3  ERS2609988
```

So if you can use the XML, you will just have to use the right xpath-syntax to get the data/nodes you need, into the columns you want...
In the exmaple above, I extracted (from each BioSample-node) the first ID-node with attribute `db` equals `SRA`, and stored the result in the co0lumn `sample_name`.

Still assuming you can use the xml-data.
If you are lokking for all attributes into one df, you need the functions from `purrr`, so just load the entire `tidyverse`

```
library( tidyverse )
df <- xml_find_all( doc, "//BioSample")  %>% 
  map_df(~{
    set_names(
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//Attribute") %>% xml_text(),
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//Attribute") %>% xml_attr( "attribute_name" )

    ) %>% 
      as.list() %>%  
      flatten_df() 
  })
```

will result in a df like this
[image]

Comment: added the part to extract all `Attribute`-nodes

Comment: I truly can't thank you enough. My machine is taking its time with the entire set, but it works beautifully :)) Thank you!!